# Blob video duration metadata

Tags: javascript, blob, mediarecorder, getusermedia, mediastream

I am writing a software that manipulates camera stream video in firefox.

I am generating a **Blob**  with video type recorded with **MediaRecorder API**.

What i am doing to save the blob as video in local storage is using **FileSaver** library :

```
    FileSaver.saveAs(BlobVideo,"video.mp4");
```

It seems the video doesnt have any max duration, so i cannot navigate in timeline in my newly generated video in VLC, for example.

Is there a way to set duration metadatas on a blob video?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem for viewing blob videos from MediaRecorder on Firefox specifically.

Answer (score 4):

This question is an almost duplicate of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443084/how-can-i-add-predefined-length-to-audio-recorded-from-mediarecorder-in-chrome/39971175#39971175). <sub>(But since there is a bounty on it, we can't vote to close)</sub>

This is a known [chrome bug](https://crbug.com/642012).

You can have this duration from the browser itself by loading the video, setting its `currentTime` to some extra-value, then reading the duration, but you won't have it attached to the file itself, at least not until the bug has been fixed.

Comment: The chrome bug mentioned here has been marked as `WontFix` by the chromium team, so it looks looks like we need to rely on a library like [ts-ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-ebml) if we want to edit the actual file.

Answer (score 4):

Until the chrome bug that Kaiido mentioned gets fixed, this worked for me:

```
while(video.duration === Infinity) {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  video.currentTime = 10000000*Math.random();
}
let duration = video.duration;
```

It would probably be a better idea to listen for the "durationchange" event though, rather than having the arbitrary 1 second pauses.

Comment: It's simple code snippet that worked for me mate, no big deal! :)