# Web MediaRecorder - Infinity duration and broken codecs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video, web-mediarecorder

I want to record user webcam stream using web's `MediaRecorder` and generate a file which has:

- correctly set duration (which can be seen and used by browsers e.g. html5 video player shows correct duration when video is in `preload` state)
- correctly set codecs for both audio and video tracks

Here you can see a fully working example (Chrome: 54.0.2840.71, Firefox: 49.0.2 -> PLEASE USE RELATIVELY NEW BROWSERS SINCE APIS USED IN THE DEMO ARE QUITE RECENT): https://jsfiddle.net/2vr7vL2p/12/ where all works perfectly besides:

- in chrome the duration returns `Infinity` (in firefox it works fine)
- in both firefox and chrome resulting file has broken codecs (for instance VLC media player returns: `VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.`)

How can one solve those issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add predefined length to audio recorded from MediaRecorder in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443084/how-can-i-add-predefined-length-to-audio-recorded-from-mediarecorder-in-chrome) For the first part. For the VLC one, that's kinda strange if it really happens on your FF and may need an other question or the edit of this one to focus on this problem only, but I can't repro, neither on my chrome nor on my FF...