# Browser MediaRecorder API - video controls not working / headers set incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, ffmpeg, mediarecorder

I'm trying to record a webcam video in the browser and save the stream on a node server.

## Approach with [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)

```
// CLIENT
// Init MediaRecorder with camera stream 
recorder = new MediaRecorder(...)
// Serialize data and send it to backend
recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data);
   reader.onloadend = function (event) {
     socket.emit('message', reader.result);
   };
}

// BACKEND
// Receive data and append it to the file
client.on('message', (data) => { 
  fs.appendFileSync(filePath + fileName + videoFileExtension, data);
  ... 
}
```

## Problem

The first time the video is played in the browser the controls for forward and backwards are not working. Once it has been played, controls are ok.

### Assumption

My assumption is that the headers are somehow broken.

## Question

Any ideas how to repair the video captured by MediaRecorder and streamed to the NodeJS? Or how to save the data chunks properly in a video file so that controls work?

Comment: Hi! This is a well known bug in Chrome; the duration of the recorded media isn't added to the headers of the final file. Sadly, this bug is currently marked as WontFix by the Chromium team. However, there are a couple of workarounds:
 - On the backend, using ffmpeg to fix the headers: ffmpeg -i old.webm output.webm
 - On the frontend, the workaround on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443084/how-can-i-add-predefined-length-to-audio-recorded-from-mediarecorder-in-chrome/39971175#39971175) or using the package [ts-ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-ebml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add predefined length to audio recorded from MediaRecorder in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443084/how-can-i-add-predefined-length-to-audio-recorded-from-mediarecorder-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

#### Here are two possible solutions

- Run `ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i video.webm -r 24 mynew.mp4` to convert from `webm` to `mp4`, this repairs the headers. You can then convert back to `webm` in a similar fashion.
- Hide the video - manually set `<video />` tag's duration to the actual duration - Chrome will jump to the end and repairs headers, controls will now work. Show the video and replay (with already corrected headers and controls).

---

I went with the first approach - convert to `mp4`.

Comment: I am also facing same problem, I have the video in mp4 format on browser but the problem is same

Comment: how can you convert webm to mp4 on browser.

Comment: my recorded video will generate in webm and mp4 but the problem is same for both

Comment: cant convert them on the browser, need to convert them server side via ffmpeg for instance (the first solution Ive suggested)

Comment: how can i convert please provide some code for this.