# Seeking is not working in recorded video with MediaRecorder API

Tags: javascript, screen-recording, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I'm trying to build a screen recording with MediaRecorder API.

**As Suggestive MediaRecorded Approach**

```
var chunks = [];
var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

recorder.streams = [stream];

recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
};

recorder.onstop = function(){
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: "video/webm"});
      chunks = [];

      var mimeType = 'video/webm';
      var fileExtension = 'webm';

      var file = new File([blob ? blob : ''], getFileName(fileExtension), {
          type: mimeType
      });
};
```

Using this approach recording is working fine, but recorded video seeking is not working.

I had done some searching on web regarding this problem, I came across that video header doesn't containing duration.

On printing `file` object on console it contains following properties,

```
lastModified : 1527592713006
lastModifiedDate : Tue May 29 2018 16:48:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
name : "Recording-May,29 2018 4:48:33 PM.webm"
size : 1971220
type : "video/webm"
webkitRelativePath : ""
```

One can see file object doesn;t contained duration property.

Can anyone suggest any javascript library available which can repairs video header on client side only while preparing the video file?

Comment: As per [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012) the length info will be missing in Chrome. Firefox [seems to have solved the problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=969290). Can you confirm you're only having the problem on Chrome?

Answer (score 8):

get a look at getSeekableBlob at https://recordrtc.org/

this is the code:

```
function getSeekableBlob(inputBlob, callback) {
    // EBML.js copyrights goes to: https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml
    if (typeof EBML === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('Please link: https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/EBML.js');
    }
    var reader = new EBML.Reader();
    var decoder = new EBML.Decoder();
    var tools = EBML.tools;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        var ebmlElms = decoder.decode(this.result);
        ebmlElms.forEach(function(element) {
            reader.read(element);
        });
        reader.stop();
        var refinedMetadataBuf = tools.makeMetadataSeekable(reader.metadatas, reader.duration, reader.cues);
        var body = this.result.slice(reader.metadataSize);
        var newBlob = new Blob([refinedMetadataBuf, body], {
            type: 'video/webm'
        });
        callback(newBlob);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(inputBlob);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and I don't need to use the full RTC library just the EBML library and this piece of code

Answer (score 6):

This is a well known bug in [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012). Basically, the duration of the recorded media isn't added to the headers of the final file.

Sadly, this bug is currently marked as `WontFix` by the Chromium team. However, there are a couple of workarounds:

- On the backend, using ffmpeg to fix the headers: ffmpeg -i old.webm output.webm
- On the frontend, the workaround on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443084/how-can-i-add-predefined-length-to-audio-recorded-from-mediarecorder-in-chrome/39971175#39971175) or using the package [ts-ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-ebml)

Answer (score 0):

A few years have passed and there is still no official solution.
The best solution I've tried so far is this `webm-duration-fix` for those who need it.
It supports fixing recording files larger than 2GB and has a low memory footprint when fixing.

```
import fixWebmDuration from 'webm-duration-fix';

const mimeType = 'video/webm\;codecs=vp9';
const blobSlice: BlobPart[] = [];

mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType
});

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event: BlobEvent) => {
  blobSlice.push(event.data);
}

mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {  
    // fix blob, support fix webm file larger than 2GB
    const fixBlob = await fixWebmDuration(new Blob([...blobSlice], { type: mimeType }));
    // to write locally, it is recommended to use fs.createWriteStream to reduce memory usage
    const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(inputPath);
    const blobReadstream = fixBlob.stream();
    const blobReader = blobReadstream.getReader();
  
    while (true) {
      let { done, value } = await blobReader.read();
      if (done) {
        console.log('write done.');
        fileWriteStream.close();
        break;
      }
      fileWriteStream.write(value);
      value = null;
    }
    blobSlice = [];
};
```