# Mediarecoder derived mp4 is missing duration metadata

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I'm attempting to use the MediaSource API to concatenate separate mp4 files that was created via the MediarRecorder API. Problem is, that there appears to be a bug in the current Chrome Browser implementation of the MediaRecorder API that omits DURATION metadata from the recorded files and unfortunately a duration value is mandatory to concatenate files together using the MediaSource API

Are there any approaches to getting around this short of using FFMPEG to re-encode the files?

Comment: So all your chunks are full files already readable? In this case you could get it from a MediaElement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443084/how-can-i-add-predefined-length-to-audio-recorded-from-mediarecorder-in-chrome/39971175#39971175 Otherwise, yes ffmpeg is the way to go (or other [EBML libs](https://github.com/cotag/ebml-parser/)).

Comment: Yes that's correct, each of the files are full mp4 files. I shall take a look at the link you provided, thank you.