# Add metadata for video which recording by MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, video, web-mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecorder to record animation from the canvas element. After downloading the video, the video information is empty (duration, bitrate, frame rate...)

[image]

Here is how I make the download URL

```js
    const blob = new Blob(data, { type: 'video/webm' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Is there any way to add metadata to download files?

Comment: Hello Quan, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443084/how-can-i-add-predefined-length-to-audio-recorded-from-mediarecorder-in-chrome To add these metadata to the recorded file you'll need postprocessing. E.g ffmpeg should be able to do that for you.

Comment: @Kaiido Here you get the `duration` for the blob recorded but we need to add that in the Blob metadata, so while treating the asset with integration, it shouldn't fail due to this missing metadata.

Comment: @dhruv479 that's why I said it's "related" and not "a dupe". Both questions are "related" to the same Chrome bug. I also said how one should handle that through postprocessing, which is obviously different than what I proposed in my answer to the other question.

Comment: I might have a possible answer for you... **(1)** How to recreate _`"using MediaRecorder to record animation from the canvas element"`_? **(2)** My solution is to just add own custom metadata bytes into the video (blob). But I need example data from step (1).

Comment: This library to write id3 tags [https://github.com/egoroof/browser-id3-writer](https://github.com/egoroof/browser-id3-writer) maybe help you!