# cant get length of m4a audio file on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, audio, m4a

I am trying to make a nodejs website that will return the length in seconds of any audio file a user chooses. So far I have it working with mp3, wav, and flac files. **But it doesn't work for all .m4a or .aif files**

The code for my HTML page with javascript is below:

```
choose audio file to get length:
<input style="cursor: pointer;" type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" />

<script>

    //when files are selected:
    $("#file").change(async function (e) {
        console.log('file(s) selected')
        //get files 
        var files = e.currentTarget.files;
        //get number of files
        var numberOfFiles = files.length;
        //for each file
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
            console.log(`songs[${i}].type=`, files[i].type)
            //get file length
            let songLength = await getSongLength(files[i]);
            console.log('songLength=', songLength)
        }

    });

    //recieve audio file, return length
    function getSongLength(song) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            console.log('getSongLength() begin setup')
            //create objectURL and audio object for ssong
            objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(song);
            mySound = new Audio([objectURL])
            console.log('getSongLength() end setup')
            //when song metadata is loaded:
            mySound.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function (e) {
                console.log('getSongLength() canplaythrough')
                var seconds = e.currentTarget.duration;
                resolve(seconds)
            });

        });
    }

</script>
```

I gathered 6 different files for testing, and after running them on my above code have found out the following results:

- aif: not working
- flac: working
- m4a_file: not working
- m4a_file_from_comments_below:not working
- mp3: working
- wav: working

my test files for download: https://easyupload.io/m/la9xro

It seems like when I input my m4a file `sample_M4A_file` that it hangs inside the `getSongLength()` function and never enters the `.addEventListener("canplaythrough"` function, is there any alternative I can use to consistently get the duration in seconds for every audio file?

[image]

Comment: Could it be the files you are using? I tried your code and it worked fine with this [m4a file](https://filesamples.com/samples/audio/m4a/sample3.m4a).

Comment: Can you please provide the file you're using to test?  The code appears to work as expected.

Comment: updated my question, the m4a file you linked does work, but my m4a file does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your browser doesn't support [Apple Lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless) codecs. If you try in Safari, it will work.
If you attach an `error` event to your media element, [you'll see it fires](https://jsfiddle.net/gcj7m3nh/).

There is no real universal solution, apart from using an heavy machinery like [mediainfo.js](https://github.com/buzz/mediainfo.js) (2.4MB+) which should support most formats.

```js
const input = document.querySelector( "input" );
input.onchange = async (evt) => {
  const mediainfo = await new Promise( (res) => MediaInfo(null, res) );

  const file = input.files[ 0 ];
  const getSize = () => file.size;
  const readChunk = async (chunkSize, offset) =>
    new Uint8Array( await file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize).arrayBuffer() );

  const info = await mediainfo.analyzeData(getSize, readChunk);
  // assumes we are only interested in audio duration
  const audio_track = info.media.track.find( (track) => track[ "@type" ] === "Audio" );
  console.log( audio_track.Duration );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mediainfo.js@0.1.4/dist/mediainfo.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
```

---

*Ps: when using the media element solution, there is no need to wait for `canplaythrough`, just wait for `loadedmetadata`, and if you get Infinity, try [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39971175/3702797).*