# Get metadata for screen captured video using JS in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-video, screen-capture, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've coded an extension able to capture screen. It works, yet the video file I download has no metadata (00:00 / 00:00 duration always, unable to scroll video). Probably, I've missed some part adding this metadata to video. How to?

(also someone gave me [this](https://dev.to/0shuvo0/lets-create-a-screen-recorder-with-js-3leb) link as an answer, but it's almost the same as my approach)

UDP: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062864/blob-video-duration-metadata/52375262#52375262) might be the solution. Yet though I can define that way duration for  tag, it doesn't work for downloaded blob. Code updated.

My code (simplified):

```
class Grabber {

    constructor(obj) {
        this.incStream = obj;
        this.recordedData = [];
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.incStream);
        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            this.recordedData.push(event.data);
        }
    }

    start() {
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    stop() {
        this.incStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            track.stop();
          });
        this.mediaRecorder.stop();
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.createFileFormCurrentRecordedData();
        }, 1000);
    }
    
async createFileFormCurrentRecordedData() {
    const blob = new Blob( this.recordedData, { type: 'video/mp4' });
    //const file = new File( [ blob ], "testScreenGrab.mp4", { type: "video/mp4"} );
    let video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    while(isNaN(video.duration) || video.duration === Infinity) {
        video.currentTime = 90000;
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
    }
    let duration = video.duration;
    console.log('Video duration: ' + duration);  
    let link  = document.createElement('a');
    link.type = "video/mp4";
    link.href = video.src;
    link.download = 'test.mp4';
    link.click();
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        const captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()
        const Grb = new Grabber(captureStream);
        Grb.start();
    }
);
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375262/13675039) might be the solution. Yet though I can define that way duration for `<video>` tag, it doesn't work for downloaded blob.

P.S.
Code updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code when try to open the output file I get:

The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player.

But I can get metadata using ffmpeg:

- Write in Terminal:

ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f ffmetadata test.txt

- Output:

Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Chrome
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
Output #0, ffmetadata, to 'test.txt':

Comment: It downloads fine for me and the file is playeble. Yet, as you wrote, there's duration N/A. So, yeah, metadata is incomplete.

Comment: I try now to open the file using Google Chrome (instead of QuickTime Player) and the file play ok using it.

Comment: I think it may be something about mimetype. I'm trying to figure it out.