# How to play HTML5 video on drag

Tags: jquery, html, video, canvas, html5-video

I want to create same effect as in scene number 2 in the [demo](http://demooo.com/wrangler/ss13/).
Please check my work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abhihshekai/8ofuLuzk/). (JsFiddle will work when you click on result area).

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br>
<input id="my-input" type="range" min="1" max="72" value="1" />
```

JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.height = 1080;
canvas.width = 1920;

var totalImages = 72;
var videoFrames = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= totalImages; i++) {
  var videoFrame = new Image;
  var videoFrameUrl = 'https://rphv.net/walkthrough/tmp-' + i + '.gif'; 
  videoFrame.src = videoFrameUrl;
  videoFrames.push(videoFrame);
}

$("#my-input").on("input", function(event) {
  var currentImage = videoFrames[event.target.value - 1];
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(currentImage, 0, 0);
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It looks like you managed to do what you want..

Comment: I have extract images from video frame by frame and implemented in canvas. But I want same effect in video and not as image

Comment: You won't have better results than these still images with a video element. changing the currentTime is asynchronous and usually requires new requests to be made. So what you are doing is probably the best you can do. However, you may be interested in a way to [programmatically extract these video frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699721/javascript-extract-video-frames-reliably/32708998#32708998) from a video element (beware extraction is made at reading speed, which means it needs some pre-loading time.

Comment: Hello Thank you very much for your reply. But what i am looking is to use  sprite images and on drag event sprite images position should be move