# Extract frames from video angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to extract frames from a video on angular. I found several post here on SO, especially this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/32708998, i've tried to implement first solution but i can't get any frame i still don't know why. So i research about it again and i found this resource [videotoframes](https://github.com/bertyhell/video-to-frames) he already has a type version, after some workaround i finally can extract the frames from video like this and put it to canvas.

[image]

But the thing is, i need to specify how many frames would i wanted from this. here's what i did

```
  loadImages() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.video.getFrames('/assets/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4', 375, VideoToFramesMethod.totalFrames).then((frames) => {
      console.log(frames);
      frames.forEach((frame) => {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = frame.width;
        canvas.height = frame.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(canvas);
      });
    });
  }
```

number `375` is an estimate how many frame my video is, is there any way to get how many frames a video have on upload?

Comment: The average HTML frame rate is 24 FPS, so if the video is 30 seconds, the total frame number is 30 x 24

Comment: so i need to assume that all of the videos will have 24 FPS then?

Comment: but can we get the video length on upload?

Comment: Length of video
`videoDOM=document.getElementById("video");
videoDom.duration` Assuming a frame rate of 24, the real calculation is complicated

Comment: perfect, it really works. Thank you, can you post on answer?

Comment: Ha ha ha, I am afraid that I am not accurate, the frame rate is usually returned to the front end after operation or back end calculation, I rarely care about this

Comment: i guess im gonna add a form so that user can specify how much their video fps is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average HTML frame rate is 24 FPS, so if the video is 30 seconds, the total frame number is 30 x 24
Get the time of the video

```
const videoDOM=document.getElementById("video"); 
videoDom.duration
```

this will give u `NaN`, so to avoid that, we need to wait for the duration to change then call `videoDom.duration`

```
videoDom.ondurationchange = () => {
   this.vidDuration = vid.duration;
};
```

that way we can get an actual duration