# HTMLMediaElement.currentTime does not appear to advance between requestMediaFrame callbacks

Tags: html5-video, requestanimationframe, drawimage

I have a fairly simple iteration that copies the content of a `<video>` into a `<canvas>`. The idea is that I start copying when the video plays and stops copying when it detects that the video has stopped playing (whether via ending or when paused).

```
play() {
    this.video.play()
    this.watch()
}

watch(previous = -1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const current = this.video.currentTime
        this.ctx.drawImage(...)
        if(current != previous) {
            this.watch(current)
            console.dir({ current, previous })
        } else {
            console.error({ current, previous })
        }
    })
}
```

If there is no `current != previous` check, the video copies fine, but it obviously doesn't ever stop copying. If the check is in place, the output reports that the first iteration is different (`previous == -1` and `current == 0`). But the second loop through (which is in the `requestAnimationFrame` callback) has `previous == 0` and also `current == 0`, so the loop stops.

I don't understand why `currentTime` is not advancing. I've called `play()` on the video, so it should be playing, especially be the time the next animation frame comes around. I've also tried making `watch()` the listener for the `video`'s `play` event, which didn't make a difference.

Comment: In addition to the solution in the posted answer (check for `paused` instead), you may want to use `video.requestVideoFrameCallback` where available. And globally, you may be interested in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699721/javascript-extract-video-frames-reliably#).

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't give you precise timestamps to avoid fingerprinting, so the currentTime likely won't be frame-accurate. Also, `requestAnimationFrame` goes at the framerate of the page, not the video content - if you want to read by video frames there's the new [WebCodecs API](https://web.dev/webcodecs/).

Check the video's `paused` or `ended` status instead of current position to know if it's done. You could also add event listeners for `pause`/`ended`.

Here's an example of doing what you want using `async` and promises:

```js
async play() {
    // returns a promise that rejects if you have audio mute problems
    await this.video.play();
    // loop until video is no longer playing. Consider including a timeout or AbortController just in case, but not totally necessary...
    while (!(this.video.paused || this.video.ended)) {
        // wrap requestAnimationFrame in promise
        await new Promise(done => {
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                this.ctx.drawImage(...);
                done();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's disappointing. I'm not looking for frame-accuracy on the source, I just wanted to minimize video effects when copying. I figured there would be some rounding, but I also figured there would be some noticeable amount of motion on the video progress once it was playing. Ah well. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: "to avoid fingerprinting" no, that's not the reason. What would a precise timestamp give on the user?

Comment: @Kaiido the link you included in your comment above is great! By fingerprinting I was referring to [this note in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime#reduced_time_precision) regarding the `currentTime` parameter. My point is that you can't necessarily use `currentTime` to get the current frame of the video

Comment: The limited timing accuracy you're talking about is much more fine-grained, and is on the order of milliseconds, not whole frames.  Playing preloaded audio with the web audio API and a buffer source gives much much more accurate timestamps (at least on mobile Chrome).  If this was caused by limiting timer accuracy then this would be affected too.  He's just seeing a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple setup to draw a video and stop drawing when paused or ended.
See if it helpful to adjusting your own code's logic.

**PS:** You likely want `requestAnimationFrame` to happen on a **Timer** rather than relying on `video.currentTime` to update as a reason to draw new frame. Time value could be updated slower than the actual video FPS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="240" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>


<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const myvid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

myvid.addEventListener("play", handle_Media_Events );
myvid.addEventListener("pause", handle_Media_Events );
myvid.addEventListener("ended", handle_Media_Events );

var my_animFrameReq;

var requestAnimationFrame = (window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame);

var cancelAnimationFrame = (window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame);


function on_timeUpdate()
{ my_animFrameReq = requestAnimationFrame(draw_video); }

function draw_video() 
{ ctx.drawImage(myvid, 0, 0, 320, 240); }

function handle_Media_Events()
{
    if ( (event.type == "pause") || (event.type == "ended") )
    { 
        cancelAnimationFrame( my_animFrameReq );
        myvid.removeEventListener("timeupdate", on_timeUpdate ); 
    }
    
    if ( event.type == "play" )
    { myvid.addEventListener("timeupdate", on_timeUpdate ); }
    
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was asking about an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I thought this was going to help out in the situation where seeking was not drawing the correct frame. Though in the end I think this might be slightly related, the answers I actually needed were to 1) do what @Luke said above, and play while the video was unpaused:

```
watch() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    this.copyFrameToCanvas()
    if(!this.video.paused) { // paused is true when ended or paused
      this.watch()
    }
  })
}
```

But also 2) to watch for [the `seeked` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seeked_event) and, when seeking, don't update the frame until the event comes in.

```
seek() {
  this.video.currentTime = $time
}

this.video.addEventListener("seeked", () => this.copyFrameToCanvas())
```

Sorry for looking for an answer to a question I didn't ask.