# How can you smoothly scrub a video on scroll?

Tags: javascript, video, canvas

I've tried setting the currentTime based on the scroll position, but the performance is really bad. Is there a better way to do it? Or is there a way to take the video and break it up into a series of images (kind of like a gif)?

Comment: _"but the performance is really bad"_ - meaning what exactly? (I imagine that if you jump towards a part of the video that has not been downloaded/cached yet, that's a delay that is hardly avoidable - unless you want to preload the whole video [and that's assuming the browser will let you].)

Comment: _"Or is there a way to take the video and break it up into a series of images"_ - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=canvas+video+screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Extract video frames reliably](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699721/javascript-extract-video-frames-reliably)

Comment: Maybe these helps: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1693593+video+frame) as well as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175174/capture-frames-from-video-with-html5-and-javascript/19176124#19176124)