# Issue with creating thumbnail from video in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to generate a thumbnail image from a video file. This is my code:

```
let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
let video: HTMLVideoElement = document.createElement('video');
video.src = video_url;
video.currentTime = 4;

video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
   canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
   canvas.height = video.videoHeight;

   video.currentTime = 4;
};

video.onloadeddata = () => {
    video.currentTime = 4;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    canvas.toBlob(thumbnailBlob => { grabThumbnail(thumbnailBlob) }, 'image/png');
};
```

It creates the image, but just a blank image. Doesn't get the video frame from the currentTime property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer in this possible duplicate of [**Capture frames from video with HTML5 and JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175174/capture-frames-from-video-with-html5-and-javascript) explains why that is and what event to use to capture the image.

Answer (score 1):

the property set on line `video.currentTime=4` is async in nature and will not give the frame image immediately. You must add event listener for the event `seeked`. In this event listener method you can generate the thumbnail of the frame at that time.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Now I'm getting a failed to execute toBlob on HTMLCanvasElement: Tainted canvases may not be exported.