# How to add preview thumbnails to html5 video seekbar

Tags: javascript, html5-video, thumbnails

So as the question states, I would like to add thumbnails to my html5 video seekbar. I would like to do this using a webvtt file.

My html5 video code...

```
<video controls>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
<track src="video.vtt" kind="metadata" default>
</video>
```

Could anyone show me an example of the javascript needed to make this work please?

An example of what I'm wanting to do is already done on the JWPlayer [here](https://support.jwplayer.com/articles/how-to-add-preview-thumbnails).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175174/capture-frames-from-video-with-html5-and-javascript/19176124#19176124) may help. Just replace the constant `i` interval with time codes from VTT file that you read and extract.