# How to input local video as input source for PoseNet?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm making a posture analyser using TensorFlow Js and PoseNet. I've made up the code to analyse postures in real time from Webcam. How do I input a local video file to be analysed?

This is the code that loads in Webcam stream. I'm looking for a way to replace this webcam video input with local video file.

```
canvas.parent('videoContainer');
video = createCapture(VIDEO);
video.size(width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so, one can use the tag `video` event listeners to get the video frames at a framerate chosen as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175174/capture-frames-from-video-with-html5-and-javascript). This is done completely client side.

The other options would be to do it server side. Using libraries such as `ffmpeg`, one can convert a video to images as used [here](https://github.com/kedevked/frameProcessing/blob/master/server/server.js)

Comment: But how do I load a local file and then serve it? I'm just using HTML and Js; nothing else.

Comment: The first link is just doing just that